# CRUD ng-grid sample with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to do CRUD in a project that uses ng-grid.

I need a sample to help me accomplish it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

Comment: there is no complete crud sample

Comment: By "CRUD" do you mean adding/deleting/editing rows ?

Comment: yes, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the best link that i followed before of simple CURD with ng-grid:

http://blog.jongallant.com/2013/05/angularjs-webapi-ef.html#.UgHtIZzxASl

The gitHub Link : https://github.com/jonbgallant/AngularJS-WebApi-EF/

Comment: @user2473037 : Wlcm..:)

Comment: that is a nice example but it does not use ng-grid